# How to allow an end user access to variables?

Tags: email, text-editor

I'm designing a form that allows an administrator to set the content of an email that will get sent out upon registration to a website. I'm assuming that the administrator will not necessarily be familiar with the concept of PHP variables, and therefore will not find the idea of typing "Hello $username" particularly friendly, resulting in unexpected mistakes and a difficult user experience.

What is the best way to handle allowing the administrator access to variables, without having to just write something like  "Type $username for the user's name to appear in the email" underneath the form?

Comment: `$username`...are you planning to `eval()` user-generated text?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I'm planning on saving the text into a database using wp_option() from Wordpress, and then echoing it into  wp_mail() with get_option() which takes care of most of the security aspects as far as I'm aware, but the feature is only available to the two owners of the business so I'm not particularly worried that they would accidentally SQL-inject themselves or anything like that.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus this is PHP. Strings are expanded on print/echo also.

Answer (score 4):

I would have a dropdown above the textarea that allows the user to select from the list of pre-defined variables (written in a user friendly way) and a button that inserts them into the textarea. I would show those variables as 'tokens' within the text, each with a control to delete.

[image]

I would also want to allow power users to type variables directly and recognise them automatically, rather than forcing everyone to use the dropdown method.

Comment: `allow power users to type variables directly` maybe when started with something like $ --- you wouldn't want to prevent them from using certain words because they're also a variable.

Comment: @bdimag use another syntax like `{{ username }}`.